# Missing SoapUI Project file.. in Testrunner.bat

Tags: soapui

I am running a project from cli and getting the following the error.

> Missing SoapUI Project file.. in Testrunner.bat

The following command I used to run from cli:

```
testrunner.bat -Pname = value "C:\Users\soapui-project.xml"
```

Output:

> SoapUI 5.4.0 Test Case Runner usage: testrunner [options]
>     -A         Turns on exporting of all results
>   using folders instead of
>               long filenames  -a         Turns on exporting of all results  -c    Sets the test case  -D    Sets system
>   property with name=value  -d    Sets the domain  -e    Sets
>   the endpoint  -f    Sets the output folder to export results to 
>   -G    Sets global property with name=value  -H    Adds a custom HTTP Header to all outgoing requests
>               (name=value), can be specified multiple times  -h    Sets the host  -I         Do not stop if error occurs, ignore them  -i
>   Enables Swing UI for scripts  -J         Sets the output to include
>   JUnit XML reports adding test
>               properties to the report  -j         Sets the output to include JUnit XML reports  -M         Creates a Test Run Log Report in
>   XML format  -m         Sets the maximum number of TestStep errors to
>   save for each
>               testcase  -P    Sets or overrides project property with name=value  -p    Sets the password  -r         Prints a
>   small summary report  -S         Saves the project after running the
>   tests  -s    Sets the testsuite  -t    Sets the
>   soapui-settings.xml file to use  -u    Sets the username  -v
>      Sets password for soapui-settings.xml file  -w    Sets
>   the WSS password type, either 'Text' or 'Digest'  -x    Sets
>   project password for decryption if project is encrypted Missing SoapUI
>   project file..

Comment: hi, could you try "C:<soapui bin path>\testrunner.bat" -Psources_path=C:\Users\soapui-project.xml, replacing soapui bin path by yours ? (ie. for me its "C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.5.0\bin\testrunner.bat")

Answer (score 1):

The error you get, is because SoapUI gets confused by the spaces.

Firstly correct your line to:

```
testrunner.bat -Pname=value "C:\Users\soapui-project.xml"
```

Now the runner will try to run the project you've got at C:\Users\soapui-project.xml
It will also set a project variable named "name" to "value", which you may modify as you want. Just remember to omit the spaces.

You may even shorten it down to just

```
testrunner.bat "C:\Users\soapui-project.xml"
```

...given that you have no project variables you want to set.